# What's the probability that a 7-digit git commit hash will be an octal number?

Tags: git, probability

Had an issue today where the git commit has was parseable as an octal number which cause a tagging issue because it was converted to decimal before being applied as a string tag.

Example:
octal      decimal
`0542764` -> `181748`

The particular issue isn't important, but was wondering the probability this would occur with any given commit.

For context this isn't an issue with git but with the integration of other tools we are using.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, an octal literal has to start with 0, and after that each subsequent digit has a 50% chance of being in the octal range, so 1/10 * (1/2)^6, I think. That's a pretty high chance, really, at 1/640! Maybe you should use more than 7 digits to identify your commits.

Comment: @joanis: 1/16 instead of 1/10, right?

Comment: 1/16 * (1/2)^6 = 1/1024, so the answer I guess is 1 in a 1000.

Comment: Right, 1/16, of course!